# rails activeadmin ask to show a input field if new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, simple-form

I have a form in [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info):

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs t('out_payment_details') do
    f.input :amount
    f.input :status
    f.input :project
    f.input :approved_user
    f.input :request_user
    f.input :from_company
    f.input :to_company
  end
  f.actions
end
```

What I want:

When new/create, `request_user` is always the `current_user`, and if edit(not create), then the `approved_user` is `current_user`.

How can I have some conditions of default value with sth like "on new form"?

Answer (score 4):

By using if and else condition like

```
if f.object.new_record? 
   input field
else
   input field
end
```